# How does sales_quote and sales_quote_adress table relate?

Tags: magento2, database, multistore, sales-quote, foreign-key

In the `sales_flat_quote` table, there is a `store_id` column. In my perspective the customer order in the front-end (website) and in the back-end, Magento creates each quote for different stores, if my understanding is correct.

While adding customer address, will Magento create a duplicate copy for each quote in the `sales_flat_quote_address` table?

How do the `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_quote_address` tables work together during checkout?

Answer (score 1):

When you add product to the cart, magento will have entries in

`sales_flat_quote`,`sales_flat_quote_item` and `sales_flat_quote_address`

ie: Carts are saved to the `sales_flat_quote` table

The items in the basket are saved to `sales_flat_quote_item`, linked by the quote's `entity_id`

Most of the entries in `sales_flat_quote_address` will be null when you create the cart. later it will be updated on checkout with proper addresses.

So when you remove a product from the cart, that product will be removed from the `sales_flat_quote_item` and `item_qty,item_count` and prices will be removed from the `sales_flat_quote` table.

This is the usual working flow. If you are not working on production please do truncate your quote tables and add product to the cart to see this changes. I think you might have missed the changes. Please do check the updated date of entries and you will definitely see the difference.

Comment: Got it, thanks. I will have a look